# Reading multiple pdf files from local storage at once

Tags: google-cloud-vision

Currently using the google vision API I am able to read just one pdf file from my local storage. I am trying to figure out how I can read multiple pdf files from local storage one at a time without having to manually change which file I want to read within my code. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirement, I referred to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/file-small-batch#local-file) .

I used the Python client library for writing the code.

My local machine directory structure :

```
home->
    myfolder->
        myfolder1->
                input1.pdf
                input2.pdf
```

I stored two pdf files in my directory and the text is extracted from the pdf files one at a time.

You can refer to the below mentioned code:

**demo.py:**

```
import io
import os

from google.cloud import vision_v1

directory="/home/myfolder/myfolder1/"
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    if  file.endswith(".pdf"):

        client = vision_v1.ImageAnnotatorClient()

# Supported mime_type: application/pdf, image/tiff, image/gif
        mime_type = "application/pdf"
        with open(os.path.join(directory,file), 'rb') as f:
            content = f.read()
        input_config = {"mime_type": mime_type, "content": content}
        features = [{"type_": vision_v1.Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION}]

# The service can process up to 5 pages per document file. Here we specify
# the first, second, and last page of the document to be processed.
        pages = [1, 2, -1]
        requests = [{"input_config": input_config, "features": features, "pages": pages}]

        response = client.batch_annotate_files(requests=requests)
        for image_response in response.responses[0].responses:
            print(u"Full text: {}".format(image_response.full_text_annotation.text))
            for page in image_response.full_text_annotation.pages:
                for block in page.blocks:
                    print(u"\nBlock confidence: {}".format(block.confidence))
                    for par in block.paragraphs:
                        print(u"\tParagraph confidence: {}".format(par.confidence))
                        for word in par.words:
                            print(u"\t\tWord confidence: {}".format(word.confidence))
                            for symbol in word.symbols:

                                print(
                                u"\t\t\tSymbol: {}, (confidence: {})".format(
                                symbol.text, symbol.confidence
                            )
                        )
```

**output:**

for input1.pdf:
[image]

for input2.pdf:
[image]